# Python ConfigParser elements into CSV arguments

Tags: python, csv, tabs, configparser

I have a script that parses a csv file and produces an XML file. One of the arguments I have to give the parser is the delimiter, which in my case is not a comma but a tab.

This information is stored in a configuration file which I extract and then pass to the csv parser.

```
ident = parser.get('CSV', 'delimiter') #delimiter taken from config file 

csv.register_dialect('custom', 
                    delimiter= ident, #passed to csv parser
                    doublequote=False,
                    escapechar=None,
                    quotechar='"',
                    quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL,
                    skipinitialspace=False)
```

However I get a type error saying that the "delimiter" must be an 1-character string. I checked the type of ident and it's a string but it doesn't seem to be recognising the \t as a tab. When I put ident = '\t' or delimiter = '\t' it works. How do I get the value correctly from the config file.

Comment: What is len(ident) and repr(ident)?

Comment: Is there whitespace around the delimiter in the config file?  Maybe you need to use strip()?  What does 'print ident' show?

Comment: len(ident) is 2 and repr(ident) is '\\t'

Comment: Sure `repr(ident)` isn't `"'\\t'"`? If printing ident shows `\t` and not just a whitespace, then `parser.get` gave you something wrong. Maybe try `delimiter=eval(ident)`?

Comment: No repr(ident) is '\\t' with both \\ in red, but printing the ident just gives \t. Also I tried eval but it threw a syntax error saying for the t char : unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: So it works if you put in the config file '\t' and then do eval. How does this work, because when i put a list of elements like [one, two, three] in the config file and the parser gives me the string but I can't get it back into a list using split. So what format do you put the elements in config file so you can extract lists/tuples etc.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit too late, but I have a small workaround: setting the parameter as the hex code value and then decoding it

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
cp = ConfigParser()
cp.add_section('a')
cp.set('a', 'b', '09') #hex code for tab (please note that there is no \x
cp.write(open('foo.ini', 'w'))

from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
cp_in = ConfigParser()
cp_in.read('foo.ini')
print(repr(bytearray.fromhex(cp_in.get('a', 'b')).decode())) #where the magic happens
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be possible using [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html).
While the docs don't explicitly mention this case, they do say that leading whitespace will be stripped from values.

Having tried to round-trip the value, it just gets back an empty string:

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
cp = ConfigParser()
cp.add_section('a')
cp.set('a', 'b', '\t')
cp.write(open('foo.ini', 'w'))

cp_in = ConfigParser()
cp_in.read('foo.ini')
print(repr(cp_in.get('a', 'b'))) # prints ''
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding what I think is the obvious answer that everyone apparently missed.  Judging from the comments, the config file looks something like this:

```
[CSV]
delimiter=\t
quoting=QUOTE_ALL
```

The value for 'delimiter' is two characters, a backslash and a 't'.  Here's how to read it and convert the value into a tab.

```
>>> import configparser, codecs, csv
>>> parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> parser.read('foo.cfg')
['foo.cfg']

>>> ident = parser.get('CSV', 'delimiter')
>>> csv.register_dialect('custom', delimiter=ident)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
>>> ident, len(ident)
('\\t', 2)

>>> decoded = codecs.decode(ident, encoding='unicode_escape')
>>> csv.register_dialect('custom', delimiter=decoded)
>>> decoded, len(decoded)
('\t', 1)
```

And here's a bonus:

```
>>> quoting = parser.get('CSV', 'quoting')
>>> csv.register_dialect('custom', quoting=quoting)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: "quoting" must be an integer
>>> quoting
'QUOTE_ALL'

>>> try:
...   quoting = parser.getint('CSV', 'quoting')
... except ValueError:
...   quoting = getattr(csv, parser.get('CSV', 'quoting'))
>>> csv.register_dialect('custom', quoting=quoting)
>>> quoting
1
```